# Elasticsearch with Django and Mongoengine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a django REST application that uses `Mongoengine`. I want to integrate the application with `elasticsearch`. I understand that databases (like `MySQL`, `Postgres` etc.) can be integrated with `elasticsearch` using `haystack` but how to do it with `MongoDB`?

Answer (score 0):

Saim, the fact you want to add elasticsearch to the stack means that you might want to index the data that is managed by mongoengine for full-text search and aggregation purposes. So you are looking for a library to index models (stored in mongo) and be accessible through the django API, I'd recommend this article [ElasticSearch with Django the easy way](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/elasticsearch-with-django-the-easy-way-909375bc16cb) where the author integrates the Django models to write into ES index via elasticsearch-py and read[search] directly using elasticsearch DSL via elasticsearch-dsl, you will realize this approach is database agnostic as well.

IMO, I have done some integrations Django<--->ES, the simpler ones, use directly the elasticsearch http api inside a Django model manager to nail the task.

Comment: Thank you. I tried something like this but it throws exception? Could you have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185509/django-haystack-and-elasticsearch-with-mongoengine